Old question suddenly appears in the first posts queue
I was presented today with this question in the first posts queue.
The question was asked on May 27, last active on June 3, and the asker hasn't been back to the site since June 13. I've emptied my view of the first posts queue many times since then. Why did this post enter the queue late or again?

This question has become the first existing posting of that user.
There had been two older posts that got deleted recently
